# How can I alter CSS styling with Javascript to make links identical to normal text?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon, readability

As you may already know, links reduce readability in online text. This is especially obvious in pages like Wikipedia science articles, where every other term is wikilinked and therefore in bright blue. I'm trying to make a Firefox addon with a toggle button that makes links appear to be normal text.

It seems reasonable that there would be a Javascript one-liner that alters the CSS styling of links in body text to whatever the underlying text style is. Am I correct in this assumption? If so, what is it? If not, what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: How would you do it with CSS?

Comment: @Xotic750: that's an approximately equivalent question, as you can edit CSS attributes with Javascript.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase it for you. If you had access to the CSS rules (i.e. the page.css file of the site), how would you write a CSS rule to make `anchor`s look like normal text? Once you know that then it is fairly simple to access those rules through [`cssRules API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) and change it.

Comment: @Xotic750: ...that's my question. I'm not a web designer (at all), so my question is probably facile, which I suspect is what you're getting at. I don't know the answer to that, though, and haven't been able to find it by searching.

Comment: Do a search on [Google](https://www.google.se/search?q=getElementByTagName&oq=getElementByTagName&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=styling+anchors+with+css&start=10) or here on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+styling+anchors) for `styling anchors with css` Once you understand that then you can attempt to use Javascript using `cssRules` (documentation linked in my comment above) There are many methods that can be used, including using libraries.

Comment: How does the saying go? `Give a man a fish and he eats for a day. Teach a man to fish and he eats for life.`

Answer (score 3):

Applying the following styles should do:

```css
a {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: inherit !important;
}
```

You can apply these styles to all webpages [using nsIStyleSheetService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service). If you only want to apply them to a single web page you should inject a `<style>` tag into the page instead.

Comment: hey wlad i was wondering my style wasnt working its some problem with the document line: @-moz-document domain(wikipedia) { a {color: black !important;} }

Comment: @Noit: this should be `domain(wikipedia.org)` of course.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this several ways. I'm not going to try to make this one line, though.  I'd probably start off with getElementByTagName if I didn't want to load or assume prior loading of jQuery.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
anchors = Array.prototype.slice.call(anchors);
anchors.forEach(function (anchor) {
    anchor.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    anchor.style.color = 'black'; // to taste
    // et. al. You'll need to define these CSS rules.
});
```

You may need to do some checking to make sure these are actually in the text of your article and not anchors from a navigation menu, sidebar, or footer.

If you really can use a one-liner, it could be something like:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function (anchor) {/* CSS */});
```

Comment: [`getElementByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a `HTMLCollection` or a `nodeList` not an `array`

Comment: Good call! Corrected.

Comment: No problem. You could equally do `Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function ...` rather than `slice` them. ;)

Comment: Indeed, but you couldn't use it as an array later on without calling 'call' every time.

Comment: It would also no longer be `live`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

to use nsIStyleSheetSercie like wlad recomended do this. just run this at startUp, make sure cssUri is a global variable, then on shutdown run the unregister function

```
var sss = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIStyleSheetService);
var ios = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var css = 'a {color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; }';
//var cssEnc = 'data:text/css;base64,' + window.btoa(css);
var cssEnc = encodeURIComponent(css);
var cssUri = makeURI('data:text/css,' + cssEnc);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
//when want to unregister run this:
//sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

this will apply style sheet to all sites. i asked wlad in comment below how to make it site speicif using @document

Comment: use this updated css in above code i gave u, in above example the underline still happens and it was not limited to wikipedia site so it would affect all ```var css = '@-moz-document domain(wikipedia.org) { a, a strong {color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; } }';```

Answer (score 0):

If vanilla JS:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
     links[i].style.appearance = 'none';
}
```

PS I haven't test edit this code.